# C program not working: program <path> does not exist VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

Long story short, I am making a calculator in c,visual studio code but when I debug it, it shows me this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuJmb.png)

I have never experienced this error before ;-;

here is my code if that helps :D

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void addition();

double division();

double subtraction();

void multiplication();



int main(){


    int opt_i;
    char opt_c;
    double opt_d;

    printf("\n\nWould you like to:");
    printf("\n1. Mutliply");
    printf("\n2.Divide");
    printf("\n3.Add");
    printf("\n4.Subtract");
    printf("\n(Choose a number)");
    scanf("%d",opt_i);

    if(opt_i==1){
        multiplication();
    }
    else if(opt_i==2){
        division();
    }
    else if(opt_i==3){
        addition();
    }
    else if(opt_i==4){
        subtraction();
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid Option :(");
        sleep(3);
        printf("Wanna restart? [y,n]");
        printf("Your option: ");
        scanf("%c",opt_c);
        if(opt_c=='y'||opt_c=='Y'){
            int main();
        }
        else if(opt_c=='n'||opt_c=='N'){
            printf("Bye <:(");
            sleep(2);
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid Option again dude check your keyboard or smth :| :O 0_0 o_o -_-");
        }
        
    }
    void multiplication();{
        int ntp;
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int num4;
        int num5;
        int ans;
        

        printf("How many number would you like to multiply?(2-5) ");
        scanf("%d",ntp);
        if(ntp==2){
            printf("Enter a number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            ans = num1*num2;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);

        }
        else if(ntp==3){
            printf("Enter a number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            printf("Enter a third number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num3);
            ans = num1*num2*num3;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);

        }
        else if(ntp==4){
            printf("Enter a number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            printf("Enter a third number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num3);
            printf("Enter a fourth number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num4);
            ans = num1*num2*num3*num4;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);
        }
        else if(ntp==5){
            printf("Enter a number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            printf("Enter a third number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num3);
            printf("Enter a fourth number to multiply: ");
            scanf("%d",&num4);
            printf("Enter a fifth and final number to multiply: ");
            ans = num1*num2*num3*num4*num5;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);

        }
    }
       
       
        void addition();{
        int ntp;
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int num4;
        int num5;
        int ans;

        printf("How many number would you like to add?(2-5) ");
        scanf("%d",ntp);
        if(ntp==2){
            printf("Enter a number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            ans = num1+num2;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);

        }
        else if(ntp==3){
            printf("Enter a number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            printf("Enter a third number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num3);
            ans = num1+num2+num3;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);

        }
        else if(ntp==4){
            printf("Enter a number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            printf("Enter a third number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num3);
            printf("Enter a fourth number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num4);
            ans = num1+num2+num3+num4;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);
        }
        else if(ntp==5){
            printf("Enter a number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
            printf("Enter the second number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num2);
            printf("Enter a third number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num3);
            printf("Enter a fourth number to add: ");
            scanf("%d",&num4);
            printf("Enter a fifth and final number to add: ");
            ans = num1+num2+num3+num4+num5;
            printf("The answer is: %d\n",ans);

        }
    }
}
```

also here is my launch.json file because when I recieve the error, it prompts me to open the launch.json file so here it is

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": false,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/ghazi/Desktop/calculator",
      "program": "c:/Users/ghazi/Desktop/calculator/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please answer this

Comment: From the image: it won't run because the linker operation failed?

Answer (score 0):

As the message states, you are unable to execute `cal.exe` because it doesn't exist.

It doesn't exist because a number of errors occurred when you tried to build it. Some of them can be seen in your screenshot.

Some of the errors stem from extraneous semi-colons in your function definitions. For example, the following semi-colon should not be there:

```c
void multiplication();{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nvm the semi colon was supposed to be there but the mistake was that I put the multiply and add functions were inside the main function

Comment: Re "*the semi colon was supposed to be there*", Absolutely not.